# How should you edit a global variable within a wordpress page template?

Tags: php, wordpress, scope, global-variables

I have a global variable:

`global $espanolGlobal;`

Declared in my functions.php file in a function utilizing the 'init' hook.

I'm trying to use the global as a persistent record of the last page the visitor was on. Or rather, whether the slug of the last page they were on ends in "-es"

So on each page i'm running something like the following:

```
global $espanolGlobal;
if (page_url_includes_substring()){
  $espanolGlobal = true;
} 
else{
  $espanolGlobal = false;
}
```

My hope was that $espanolGlobal would then hold this value on the next page that is loaded. So that I can do something like

```
if($espanolGlobal == true){
//the last page was in Spanish, do x
}
else{
//the last page was in English, do y
}
```

The value of $espanolGlobal, however doesn't seem to persist to the next page.

In short, **is there a way to pass a global variable a new value locally that can be accessed site wide?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global variables are global but NOT persistent, i.e. they do not retain their values from one invocation of WordPress to the next invocation. In your case I think you need persistence per user so HTTP cookies would work as these are persistent over a browser session. If you want a PHP solution you need to store something in the MySQL database as only data in the database will persist from one invocation of WordPress to the next. Actually, storing something in the file system would also be persistent but in WordPress persistent data is conventionally store in the database.

Comment: Thank you, I thought this might be the case. But I could not find a resource online that clearly stated as much.

Comment: Have you considered the HTTP variable 'Referer'?